# NoClassDefFoundError in FragmentMapActivity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I've seen this question asked often, but none of the proposed solutions seem to be working for me.  I'm getting

```
E/AndroidRuntime(897): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.FragmentMapActivity$4
```

when attempting to open a new FragmentMapActivity.

Code:

```
public class Maps extends FragmentMapActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps_simple);

  //MapView for the lose :(
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.map_warning, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    MapView mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

R.layout.maps_simple contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="<key removed for security>"
    />
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="osmstudios.mappingapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.MapApp" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".AppMainActivity">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.keyes.youtube.OpenYouTubePlayerActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Maps">
        <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                   <category android:name="osmstudios.mappingapp" />
                </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the inner code of the button press that opens the FragmentMapActivity intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, Maps.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Finally, this is what my Libraries folder in the Java Build Path tool look like:
[image: libraries]

I've been really beating my head against a wall on this one.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue had to do with a change in Android versions.

More information and the fix can be found http://www.wiseappsllc.com/homepage/android-dev-tips

Answer (score 3):

This is bit late but I had the exact same issue and could at least resolve the "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:". In project property->java Build path -> Libraries, I had included android-support-v4.jar from android sdk path. This lib was available during compile time but not at run time. You need to copy this jar from sdk path to application libs location that way this lib is statically added to your app and could be found during run time. hope this helps. This solution I found after lots of search in StackOverFlow. Hers is the link. [Trying to use DialogFragments via v4 compatability causes NoClassDefFoundErrors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320378/trying-to-use-dialogfragments-via-v4-compatability-causes-noclassdeffounderrors)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the issue, but I've already rewritten the application so I can't test.  I appreciate you taking the time to post your findings.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, then i resolved it by checking the build path of the project. There i had two map jars. I deleted one in libraries, Now it is working fine. Just check it may work.